# ASP.NET Core JWT Bearer Authentication with external Windows Authentication possibility

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, jwt

I want to use ASP.NET Core JWT Bearer Authentication with Windows Authentication. Is this possible? I haven't found the right way to implement it.

### Current implementation

My current implementation is auth through Windows, save authentication data in temporary cookies. Then I redirect to another action, that checks temporary cookies and if the external scheme(Windows in my case) is authenticated successfully, generates JWT token and clears temporary cookies.

#### Second api call to generate token

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(AuthenticationDefaults.ExternalCookiesScheme);
if (result?.Succeeded != true) {
  throw new Exception("External authentication error");
}
string jwtToken = JwtFactory.GenerateJSONWebToken(result.Principal.Claims);

await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(AuthenticationDefaults.ExternalCookiesScheme);

Response.Headers.Add("JWTToken", jwtToken);

return new OkResult();
```

I am not sure that using temporary cookies it's the right way.

*How can I implement it? Or saving external authentication data in temporary cookies is correct and my implementation is ok?*

## Update

I found Dino Esposito article about it => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/cutting-edge-cookies-claims-and-authentication-in-asp-net-core#external-authentication

There are cookies used for external authentication, so now I am a little more confident in using my implementation.

Anyway, I will be glad to see more options for external windows authentication with jwt token generation

Comment: Don't shout please. This won't attract answers, quite the opposite

Comment: JWT is a standard used to specify some claims (eg user identity, group membership etc). It's not directly tied to any authentication mechanism, you can create such a token and fill it with anything you want, including the Windows identity and user roles. Its use is described by the standard - it **must** be transferred using [specific headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Use), not cookies.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I mean I use cookies to store temporary auth data(claims) after external auth before creating a token, not to transfer token via cookies

Comment: So the real question is where to store the token on the browser. This has little to do with external authentication. From the Wikipedia article's `Use` section - `a JSON Web Token will be returned and must be saved locally (typically in local or session storage, but cookies can also be used)`